# Sum of series scaled by the harmonic series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, harmonic-numbers

Let $\{ a_k \}$ so that $\sum_{k=1}^n a_k = A_n$. We can also assume that $A_n \rightarrow A$.

It is known that $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1k \approx \ln(n)$.  Is there a way to approximate $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{a_k}{k}$ ?

Answer (score 1):

If we suppose that the sequence $(a_k)_{k>0}$ is positive, then $(A_k)_{k>0}$ is increasing, so by Abel summation we get :
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{a_k}{k}=\frac{A_n}{n+1}+\sum_{k=1}^nA_k\biggl(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1}\biggr)$$
Therefore we have this inequality :
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{a_k}{k}⩽\frac{A}{n+1}+A\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1}=A$$
Or using Landau notation, 
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{a_k}{k}=O(1)$$

Comment: Thanks but 1) $a_n$ need not be positive and 2) This is just a trivial upper bound, not an approximation

Comment: @catch22 The first equation is a valid approximation which doesn’t require positivity.  Note that the series on the right has terms of size $O(1/k^2)$.  If you have some measure of the convergence of $A_k$ you can use it to approximate the tail terms at any cutoff you desire.  As you’d expect, the exact value of the sum depends highly on the early terms.  The details would depend on how much you know about $A_k$.